# Using lower_bound() and upper_bound() to select records

Tags: c++

I have a map of objects, keyed by a date (stored as a double). I want to filter/extract the objects based on date, so I wrote a function similar to the snippet below.

However, I found that if I provide a date that is either lower than the earliest date, or greater than the last date, the code fails. I have modified the  code so that any input startdate that is lower than the first date is set to the first (i.e. lowest) date in the map, likewise, enddate  > last date is set to the last (greatest) date in the map

```
void extractDataRecords(const DatedRecordset& recs, OutStruct& out, const double startdt, const double enddt)
{
    double first = recs.begin()->first, last = recs.rbegin()->first;
    const double sdate = (start < first) ? first : startdt;
    const double edate = (enddt > last) ? last : enddt;

    DatedRecordsetConstIter start_iter = recs.lower_bound(sdate), end_iter = recs.upper_bound(edate);

    if ((start_iter != recs.end()) && (end_iter != recs.end()))
    {

        // do Something
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: What does "the code fails" mean?  If `startdt <= recs.begin()->first`, then `recs.lower_bound(startdt)` should give you `recs.begin()`.

Answer (score 9):

`std::lower_bound` returns: "the first position into which `value` can be inserted without violating the ordering." `std::upper_bound` returns: "the furthermost position into which `value` can be inserted without violating the ordering." In other words, if you insert the new item at either position, you're guaranteed that the overall ordering of the collection remains intact.

If you're going to use both anyway, you should probably use `std::equal_range` instead -- it returns an `std::pair` of iterators, one that's the same as `lower_bound` would have returned, and the other the same as `upper_bound` would have returned. Although it has the same worst-case complexity as calling the two separately, it's usually faster than two separate calls.

It's worth noting, however that if what you have is really a `map` (rather than a `multimap`) there can only be one entry with a given key, so there's not much reason to deal with both `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` for any given key.

Answer (score 0):

From GNU [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a00439.html#08d1259712c50945a7a37d48d15d461b)

> ```
> lower_bound:
> This function returns the first element of a subsequence of elements
> ```
>
> that matches the given key. If
>   unsuccessful it returns an iterator
>   pointing to the first element that has
>   a greater value than given key or
>   end() if no such element exists

Your original approach on using `lower_bound` sounds correct to me. However, I think you don't need to use `upper_bound`, you can do a simple comparison with `enddt`. I would try

```
for( DatadRecordsetConstIter cit = recs.lower_bound( startdt ); 
        cit != rec.end(); ++cit ) {

    if( *cit > enddt ) {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff with *cit
}
```